# Setting up dependencies with head.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, head.js

I just started using head.js for loading JS files asynchronously with dependencies.

Looking at the API documentation and examples, I see that you can apply labels to JS files, then run some conditions when they are loaded, heres an example in their documentation:

```
// same as above, but pass files in as an Array
head.load([
    { label1: "file1.js" }, 
    { label2: "file2.js" }], 
    function() {
    // do something
});

// Labels are usually used in conjuntion with: head.ready()
head.ready("label1", function() {
    // do something
});
```

So basically, that will execute anything in the 2nd block of code (inside the closure), when the file1.js is loaded.

What I wanted to do, is load more files (asynchronously) when other files are loaded..

For example..

1. First, load the jquery file: jquery.min.ks
2. After thats successfully loaded, asynchronously load DataTables files: [ dataTables.searchHighlight.min.js, dataTables.conditionalPaging.js, jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js ]
3. After that, load the main application files: [ myapp_core.js, myapp_whatever.js ]

Heres the code I have now, using head.js, It seems to work ok, but it just doesn't seem right (Having to throw head.load() inside other functions)

```
// Step #1
head.load(
    // First, load the main JS library
    [
        { jquery_core: "/include/plugins/jquery-1.11.3/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" },
        { jquery_ui: "/include/plugins/jquery-ui-1.10.4/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js" }
    ],
    function() {
        console.debug('Loaded jQuery library files, loading jQuery plugin files..');
        jquery_plugins();
    }
);


// Step #2
function jquery_plugins() {
    head.load([
            // Load all the jQuery plugin files
            "/include/plugins/bootstrap-3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js",

            "/include/plugins/select2/select2.js",
            "/include/plugins/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/bootstrap3-editable/inputs-ext/address/address.js",
            "/include/plugins/bootstrap3-editable/inputs-ext/typeaheadjs/lib/typeahead.js",
            "/include/plugins/bootstrap3-editable/inputs-ext/typeaheadjs/typeaheadjs.js",
            "/include/plugins/bootstrap3-editable/inputs-ext/wysihtml5/wysihtml5.js",

            "/include/plugins/mustache/mustache.js",

            "/include/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js",
            "/include/plugins/gritter/js/jquery.gritter.js",
            "/include/plugins/jquery-tooltipster-master/js/jquery.tooltipster.js",
            "/include/plugins/bootstrap-wizard/js/bwizard.js",
            "/include/js/apps.js",
            "/include/js/enhanced-select.jquery.min.js",
            "/include/js/jquery.multi-select.js",
            "/include/plugins/intro/intro.js",
            "/include/plugins/switchery/switchery.min.js",
            "/include/js/jquery.multiselect.js",
            "/include/plugins/parsley/src/parsley.js",
            "/include/plugins/parsley/src/extra/validator/APPcustom.js",
            "/include/plugins/parsley/src/extra/plugin/parsley.remote.js",
            "/include/plugins/bootstrap3-timepicker2/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js",
            "/include/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
            "/include/plugins/SamWM/numeric/jquery.numeric.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/moment/moment.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.stack.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.crosshair.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js",
            "/include/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js",
            "/include/plugins/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput-typeahead.js",
            "/include/plugins/jquery-tag-it/js/tag-it.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/contextMenu/src/jquery.ui.position.js",
            "/include/plugins/contextMenu/src/jquery.contextMenu.js",
            "/include/js/jquery.mask.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/jquery-jstree/dist/jstree.min.js",
            "/include/plugins/jquery.expander.js",
            "/include/plugins/jquery-labelauty/source/jquery-labelauty.js",
            "/include/plugins/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js",

            "/include/plugins/jquery-jscroll/jquery.jscroll.js",
            "/include/js/modernizr.js",
            "/include/plugins/jquery-messi/dist/messi.js",

            "/include/plugins/jquery-tmpl/jquery.tmpl.min.js",

            { jquery_highlight: "/include/plugins/jquery-searchhighlight/jquery.highlight.js" },

            { datatables_core: "/include/plugins/DataTables/minify/datatables.min.js" },
            { datatables_searchHighlight: "/include/plugins/DataTables-Plugins/features/searchHighlight/dataTables.searchHighlight.min.js" },
            { datatables_conditionalPaging: "/include/plugins/DataTables-Plugins/features/conditionalPaging/dataTables.conditionalPaging.js" },
            { datatables_ellipsis: "/include/plugins/DataTables-Plugins/dataRender/ellipsis.js" },
            { datatables_yadcf: "/include/plugins/yadcf-0.8.8/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js" },

            { ckeditor: "/include/plugins/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" }
        ],
        function() {
            console.log('All jQuery plugins loaded, loading APP js files...');
            APP_js_files();
        });
}

// Step #3
function APP_js_files(){
    head.load([
            // Load the application JS files
            { APP_plugins: "/include/js/APP_plugin.js" },
            { APP_intro: "/include/js/APP_intro.js" },
            { APP_app: "/include/js/APP_app.js" },
            { APP_confirmation: "/include/js/APP_confirmation.js" }
        ],
        function() {
            "use strict";
            console.log('Successfully loaded all APP js files!');

            $.ajaxSetup({
                cache:false
            });

            App.init();


            template.init();
            account.init();
            admin.init();
            assets.init();
            forms.init();
        });
}
```

The above code is inside init.js, which is loaded via..

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/include/js/head.min.js" data-headjs-load="/include/js/init.js"></script>`

Is this the right way to do it? The documentation on head.js is pretty limited.

Thanks

Comment: Im thinking about using RequireJS instead, but id like to use this for CSS as well. I dont get how HeadJS can include CSS, but ReqireJS cant, its either RequireJS doesnt know something that HeadJS knows, or HeadJS settled for something they probably shouldnt have

Answer (score 0):

Current implementation don't support query or ordering of loading, as I can sas in source code, that's why your solution of the problem is one of the best.